# activity items(textview and some buttons) are not showing properly

Tags: android

I have a text view and 9 buttons . textview's text suppose to change when i click on each button.
But the problem is the items are not showing properly 
the app is suppose to be like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nI5o.png
and here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="#B8D509"
        android:textColor="#03415A"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="100dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="502dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="502dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="307dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="502dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="589dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="589dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="306dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="589dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="666dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="665dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="305dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="666dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but the result is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLgcB.jpg
please tell me what should i do to have my app exactly like android studio's preview

Comment: ConstraintLayout is tricky to use and should be avoided unless you knoe what you're doing. `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` only affects editor, not the real app just like the name implies. You can make a layout like yours with several LinearLayouts and margins. Might throw in some weights

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **constraints** of your `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#B8D509"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#03415A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @pouria did you try it?